# Why does this 'b' linked list changed?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have 2 linked lists:

'a': 1->2->3->null

'b': 4->5->null

I want to merge them together as : 1->4->2->5->3->null

I write a function:

```
    private void merge(ListNode a, ListNode b){
        ListNode cur = new ListNode(0);
        
        while(a != null && b != null){
            cur.next = a;
            cur = cur.next;
     
            cur.next = b;
            cur = cur.next;
            
            b=b.next;
            a=a.next;
        }
        if(a==null && b==null) return;
        else if(a==null){
            cur.next = b;
        }else if(b==null){
            cur.next = a;
        }
        return;
    }
```

what I think is to use a 'cur' to record each node in these 2 linked list 'a' and 'b'. Then these 2 linked lists 'a' and 'b' move to its next node. Then go to the next WHILE loop.

However, it's wrong. When I debug, in this first WHILE loop, when it finished this

```
cur.next = b;
```

it shows that variables will change as follow:

```
a: [1,5,4]
b: [5,4]
cur: [1,5,4]
```

**I'm so confused why 'a' linked list will change to [1,5,4]? I think 'a' linked list won't change at this point, it keeps as [1,2,3].**

--------But when I change WHILE loop as this following, it works:

```
    while(a != null && b != null){
            cur.next = a;
            a=a.next;
            cur = cur.next;
            cur.next = b;
            b=b.next;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
```

**So my question is:
what's the difference between these two WHILE loop?**

```
    while(a != null && b != null){
            cur.next = a;
            a=a.next;
            cur = cur.next;

            cur.next = b;
            b=b.next;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
```

```
while(a != null && b != null){
            cur.next = a;
            cur = cur.next;
     
            cur.next = b;
            cur = cur.next;
            
            b=b.next;
            a=a.next;
        }
```

Comment: Call you clarify what behavior you expect? Right now, you're definitely modifying the input lists.

Comment: Try performing all the operations using pen and paper. Draw boxes for the nodes, and arrows between the boxes for the `next` link. Erase and redraw arrows as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that when `cur` points to a node whose next is still needed you still cannot assign to next.

Tip at the end of a method `return;` is not needed.

It may help to first use *recursion*, doing an easy bit of work, and call other instances of the same method for the rest.

A recursion would be:

```
private ListNode merge(ListNode a, ListNode b) {
    if (a == null) {
        return b;
    } else if (b == null) {
        return a;
    }
    ListNode anext = a.next;
    a.next = merge(b, a.next);
    return a;
}
```

which becomes iterative:

```
private ListNode merge(ListNode a, ListNode b) {
    while (true) {
        if (a == null) {
            return b;
        } else if (b == null) {
            return a;
        }
        ListNode anext = a.next;
        a.next = b;

        a = b;
        b = anext;
    }
}
```

This handles lists with different lengths, and hence needs a result.

The difficult point is that instead of taking two steps a.next and b.next the call's arguments are switched.

Your version puts the results in `a` and requires that both lists have the same length.
`a` being null and `b` not so would not be possible.

In your first version a 0 element is first introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a bug in your while loop . For a correct merge algorithm  your loop invariant should be at the end of each iteration in the while loop `ListNode` a and b should point to next element in their **respective** list .

```
while(a != null && b != null){
            cur.next = a;
            cur = cur.next;
     
            cur.next = b;
            cur = cur.next;
            
            b=b.next; 
            a=a.next; // you are making a point to node in list b , which is wrong .
        }
```

From  your test  data

List a :  1 -> 2 -3
List b :  4 -> 5

Lets check the invariant of your while loop after 1st iteration

(i)  `a=a.next` sets  a to first node in b i.e 4 whilst it should point to next element in its own list `1->2->3` i.e 2

This breaks your algorithm.